# Using Net::OpenSSH tail the message file and grep

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I am using [`Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$linux_machine_host")
```

Using the SSH object, fews commands are executed multiple times for N hours.

At times I need to look for any error messages, such as *Timeout*, in the `var/adm/message` file.

#### My suggestion

```
$ssh->capture2("echo START >> /var/adm/messages");
```

```
$ssh->capture2("some command which will be run in background for n hours");
```

```
$ssh->capture2("echo END >> /var/adm/messages");
```

Then read all lines between `START` and `END` and grep for the required error message.

```
$ssh->capture2("grep -A 100000 "START" /var/adm/messages | grep -B 100000 END");`
```

Without writing `START` and `END` into the message file, can I `tail` the `var/adm/message` file at some point and capture any new messages appearing afterwards.

Are there any `Net::OpenSSH` methods which would capture new lines and write them into a file?

Comment: What happened when you tried using `echo`? Why don't you use the Perl program to filter the logs?

Comment: Perl program involves reading the message file which would have more than a lakh lines. Whenever I look for a error message, File handle reads each line from the beginning of the file(which is very time taking process).

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `messages` file via SFTP (see [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign)):

```
# untested!
use Net::SFTP::Foreign::Constants qw(:flags);

...
my $sftp = $ssh->sftp;
# open the messages file creating it if it doesn't exist
# and move to the end:
my $fh = $sftp->open("/var/adm/messages",
                     SSH2_FXF_READ|SSH2_FXF_CREAT)
    or die $sftp->error;
seek($fh, 0, 2);

$ssh->capture2("some command which...");

# look for the size of /var/adm/messages now so that we
# can ignore any lines that may be appended while we are
# reading it:
my $end = (stat $fh)[7];

# and finally read any lines added since we opened it:
my @msg;
while (1) {
    my $pos = tell $fh;
    last if $pos < 0 or $pos >= $end;
    my $line = <$fh>;
    last unless defined $line;
    push @msg, $line;
}
```

Note that you are not taking into account that the messages file may be rotated. Handling that would require more convoluted approaches.